Is there a way to enable, pause, resume chrome devtools?
Preq:

Launch selenium script in python
Once launched we are trying to connect to chrome devtools and
control the execution of script for debugging.
As and when selenium script starts replaying, I'm fetching websocket
url and executing below  code snippet.

Below is my code snippet to connect to chrome devtools through python
def connect_devtools(ws_url):
        global ws
        ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(ws_url,
                                   on_open=on_open,
                                   on_message=on_message,
                                   on_error=on_error,
                                   on_close=on_close)
        # Run WebSocket in a separate thread to keep it open
        wst = threading.Thread(target=ws.run_forever)
        wst.daemon = True
        wst.start()
        time.sleep(1)  # Wait for the connection to be established

def enable_debugger():
    enable_debugger_command = {
        "id": 1,
        "method": "Debugger.enable",
        "params": {}
    }
    ws.send(json.dumps(enable_debugger_command))

def pause_debugger():
    if ws:
        pause_command = {
            "id": 2,
            "method": "Debugger.pause",
            "params": {}
        }
        ws.send(json.dumps(pause_command))
    else:
        print("WebSocket is not connected")

def on_open(ws):
    print("WebSocket connection opened")


def on_message(ws, message):
    print("Received message: ", message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ws_url = "ws://127.0.0.1:35192/devtools/browser/9e552787-2329-4e7d-9cca-77a60e8d603c"  # Replace with your actual WebSocket URL
    connect_devtools(ws_url)  

 # Wait a bit before pausing to see the effect
  time.sleep(2)
  enable_debugger
  pause_debugger()

I see below output:
WebSocket connection opened
Received message:  {"id":1,"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"'Debugger.enable' wasn't found"}}
Received message:  {"id":2,"error":{"code":-32601,"message":"'Debugger.pause' wasn't found"}}

As we can see here, websocket connection is opened but unable to pause.
Is there a way to enable, pause, resume chrome devtools without debugger?

Yes. There will be some way like enabling chrome settings to enable, pause, and resume chrome DevTools.

can you please give a reference or more info on how exactly we can enable pause and resume.
